# Vector of type <Object*> and traversing

Tags: c++, c++11

This most probably seems like a basic question to most however I don't know.

Lets say I make a class aTask;

```
    Class aTask{


    string taskID;
    int taskDuration;
    std::vector<aTask*> taskList;

    //copy constructor and such

    aTask(const string& id, int duration){
        taskDuraion = duration;
        TaskId = id;
    }

    Task& predecessor(int index) const{

        for (std::vector<Task*>::iterator it = taskList.begin(); it != taskList.end(); ++it) {
                //do stuff
            }
    }

    }
```

The compile will not allow me to write taskList.begin() or taskList.end() in the for loop definition of the function predecessor. The compiler tells me,

```
> **no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Task
> *>>>" to "std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Task *>>>"
> exists**
```

If you would be so kind as to tell me what I need to do?

Comment: You need a const_iterator. I suggest using `auto` so you don't have to type it all out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `predecessor` is `const` meaning that the `this`-pointer inside `predecessor` is `const` meaning that `taskList` is `const`. `taskList.begin()` will return a `std::vector<Task*>::const_iterator` which is not convertible to a `std::vector<Task*>::iterator`, because that would break const-correctness.

To fix the issue you could use a `std::vector<Task*>::const_iterator` as mentioned in the comments. But since you tagged [c++11] there are much better ways:

```
//no need to worry about complicated types
for (auto it = begin(taskList); it != end(taskList); ++it){
    //do stuff
}

//no need to worry about anything
for (auto &&task : taskList){
    //do stuff
}
```

Of course these also preserve const-correctness, so modifying `it` or `task` is not possible unless you remove `const` from `predecessor`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `predecessor` function is `const`, the access to members on `aTask` should also be `const`. The `it` variable should be declared as `std::vector<Task*>::const_iterator` or, in C++11, you can use `auto`.

```
Task& predecessor(int index) const {
    for (auto it = taskList.begin(); it != taskList.end(); ++it) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```